# Add Tabs to ViewPager dynamically based on the JSON key

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I get the JSON data for different events in JSON and as per the format (format attached below) I created a `event` class according to the keys in each `event`. Then I put all the `events` data into an `events ArrayList` while I parse the JSON and later-on I show that in a `ListView` using custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` - Everything works fine uptill here and the events are showing in ListView.

But what I'm trying to do now is to have a ViewPager and `Tabs` in ViewPager are generated dynamically according to the Dates. Like if there are 3 different dates in Schedule (Some events happening on one date and others are happening on other date), ViewPager gets 3 Tabs and in each tab the events only for that respective date are shown in `ListView`so user can see events for specific date by selecting that date tab. Unfortunately, I have been stuck over it and unable to achieve it.

Kindly guide and help me with this as how should I proceed to achieve this (i.e tabs are generated dynamically as per the different dates and show respective events only ) ?

p.s the Event JSON has a key `date`.

Thanks in advance :)

---

The JSON for Schedule that I parse to get date:

```
[
{
    "title": "Opening",
    "subtitle": "might be there",
    "start": "13:30",
    "end": "14:30",
    "location": "B01.063",
    "date": "2014-08-01",
    "authors": ["George Martin"],
    "type": "talk",
    "abstract": "http://..."
},
{
    "title": "Coffe break",
    "subtitle": "might be there",
    "start": "16:15",
    "end": "17:00",
    "location": "Crown room",
    "date": "2014-08-02",
    "authors": [],
    "type": "break",
    "abstract": "http://..."
}
]
```

---

Event Class:

```
public class EventScheduleItem {

private String title;

private String subtitle;

private String start;

private String end;

private String location;

private String date;

private String authors;

private String type;

private String eventAbstract;

//here are getter/setters and constructor for this class

}
```

---

And this is how i create the Events Arraylist:

`List<EventScheduleItem> eventsRecordsArray = new ArrayList<EventScheduleItem>() ;`

**EDIT:**

```
private class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Something should go there which I don't know what should i do to get events for the date
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return eventsarray.length; //This too i guess is wrong since Tabs coun't would be based on different dates
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have been stuck over it and unable to achieve it" -- please show the `PagerAdapter` implementation that you tried and explain what problems you encountered with it.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried to implement it in vein - don't have clue how to go over it to achieve it, because my arraylist of events has `events` but if i override the getcount() and return the length of array that's not working. Kindly help me with this Sir, I shall be extremely grateful for this. And I believe that the solution you would guide me will be one of the best and most optimized.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir kindly guide me for this please, how should I proceed.

Comment: What does "that's not working" mean? You have told us a lot about things that we do not need to know (e.g., JSON formats) and next to nothing about **specifically** what you tried and **specifically** what problems that you encountered. You have answered 115 questions here on Stack Overflow, so surely you know what makes a good question. Show us your `PagerAdapter` and tell us what did and did not work with it, in more detail than "that's not working".

Comment: @CommonsWare Sir, I'm new to Android and still learning the concepts. The problem is primarily with the approach I need to use for achieving the purpose. Like should i first traverse the events array to find different dates and then make separate array (e.g arrayX) and maintain index of event (from main array call that arrayY )and date in separate array ?And after that, would it be loading same fragment in each event and then get event indexes of that date  from arrayX and then find the events from arrayY ? I edited Question & added the `PagerAdapter`code which i was trying.Kindly help, please

Comment: I am having difficulty interpreting your questions. In general, to implement "if there are 3 different dates in Schedule... ViewPager gets 3 Tabs", you would want to have a data model organized that way, such as an `ArrayList<EventScheduleDate>`, where an `EventScheduleDate` knows the date and the `EventScheduleItems` that belong to that date. Then, your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` would return `getCount()` based on the size of the `ArrayList`, and `getItem()` would return a `Fragment` instance that knows how to render a specific `EventScheduleDate` instance.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thankyou very much Sir. I changed the data model to group events for date as you advised, and it's now working :) Thankyou for the support and time.

Comment: @CommonsWare : A request - Kindly have a look at my this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25036709/1906361 and suggest solution for this please. Need help with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your activity:

```
String[] tabs = {"Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3"};
mAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs);
```

And in your pager adapter

```
private class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    String[] tabs;
    public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String[] tabs) {
        super(fragmentManager);
        this.tabs = tabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Something should go there which I don't know what should i do to get events for the date
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return tabs.length();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tabs[position];
    }
}
```