# Actionbar Back/Home Arrow Padding and Pressed State

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I wanted to have up/home arrow button in my activity ActionBar to provide users option for navigating up. In my activity, I have set  set  `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and also have defined `parentActiviy` in Manifest like this:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.g_node.gca.map.MapActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="com.g_node.gca.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_map" >
</activity>
```

It works and I see a left-arrow icon before the icon in ActionBar, that onClick takes back to parentActivity. But I don't see any change in state of actionbar title or icon, when it's clicked/pressed.

**How can I style that so when user clicks on that icon, it shows a `pressed` state? Like in following screenshot:**

[image]

Moreover, **How can I set the padding between the left-arrow icon and the actionbar icon ?** In my activity actionbar, both are almost sticked, see screenshot below for reference:

[image]

One more thing - I'm setting this icon in my activity pragmatically using `getActionBar().setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_maps));` and icon size is 128 x 128.

Thankyou in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background by setting the actionBarItemBackground attribute in your theme. This should be a state-list drawable which reflects states such as pressed and focused.

@android:color/transparent